# Accessing files on password protected server

Tags: objective-c, authentication, html-parsing, hpple, mknetworkkit

I've been retrieving documents from a public web server by going to the URL and parsing the HTML tree with TFHpple, like this:

```
NSData *documentsHTMLData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
TFHpple *documentsParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:documentsHTMLData];
....
....
```

The server is now being password protected and I was hoping to still be able to access it, perhaps using MKNetworkKit. I've got as far as:

```
MKNetworkEngine *myEngine = [[MKNetworkEngine alloc] init];
MKNetworkOperation *user = [myEngine operationWithURLString:myURL];
[user setUsername:@"test" password:@"test"];
[myEngine enqueueOperation:user];
```

but have no idea where to go from there with MKNetworkKit regarding how to then get access to directory structure.

I was hoping someone here might be able to point me in the right direction. 
Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your server is password protected, you need to know the authentication scheme used.
If your server uses HTTP Basic/Digest authentication, your code above should just work. If your server serves you a HTML page and asks you to type a username/password (aka, HTTP+HTML Form based authentication) you are out of luck, unless you reverse engineer and find a workaround.

Comment: @Munguth: Thanks for the reply. I believe it uses HTTP basic authentication, in so far as encoding the url as `http://user:password@myURL` allows access. I think the code above works OK but I'm confused as to how to get visibility of directory. I tried simply putting the first code snippet after the second but that didn't work.

Comment: Try using the method [user addCompletionHandler:errorHandler:] and get the response string from the completion handler. The response string will be the HTML from where you should parse the data. The url should *NOT* contain user:password. MKNetworkKit does this internally.